# Adviseable Git repository structure for a Maven Project to be used from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, github

I have an Eclipse maven project which I have moved to GitHub recently. The directory structure is like this:

```
Git Repo
|__Eclipse Folder
|____src
|____pom.xml
```

The problem with this is when my teammates clone the project in Eclipse they cannot convert it to a maven project so I have to change the structure as:

```
Git Repo 
|__src
|__pom.xml
```

Is there any elegant way to handle this?

Comment: This question is quite interesting and something I've wondered before. I think the title needs a rename, but I'm not sure what to.

Comment: I don't know if it would be a clean solution, but make a maven module could work.

Comment: The second structure is the correct one...

Comment: @byxor I have edited the title, hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue seem to be that your Eclipse and Github project do not have the same name so you have a project folder inside your Github folder.

What would be an ideal solution in this case is to use the Git_Root_Repository as the Eclipse_project_folder as seen on [this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) to keep a neat Github repo.

To achieve this try to move the src/ and pom.xml up directly under the Git_Root_Repository and re-import the project as a Maven project in Eclipse.

Comment: I have pretty much followed what you have suggested. But the reason to end up with such structure was different. I had an eclipse project already connected to a different VCS. We now have to migrate it to GitHub. As per the best practice I should create the Git repo outside my Eclipse workspace. That's how I ended up one extra folder above the Eclipse project root. But later I found out that's not ideal for Maven projects. I will accept your answer anyway. Thanks.